# Why does count(column) and count(*) return the same output, even when there is a NULL value in a record?

Tags: mysql, count

I have a sample table called test, that includes a `null` value in one of the columns called marks. The table has 8 records. When I run the following query :

```
select count(marks) from test;
```

I get 7, which is fine as the `null` value is ignored. Since the table has 8 records, `count(*)` gives me 8. But what is confusing is that when I run both these together as under:

```
select count(marks),count(*) from test;
```

I get as output 8  for both. Why is count (marks) not ignoring the `null` value here?

Sample table:

[image]

Comment: which version of mysql you are using ??'

Comment: Cannot reproduce on any MySQL or MariaDB supported by [sqlfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=69a6a2750d9a9957e481b09cedfe22a2) - all versions return `7, 8` for `SELECT COUNT(marks), COUNT(*) FROM t;`.

Comment: @scaisEdge I am using MySQL 8.0 on MySQL Workbench.

Comment: Can you also try with the code I posted above (in sqlfiddle)? If you are getting my results, see what's different between your example and mine. If you are getting `8, 8` again, you probably [found a bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/) in your build.

Comment: @Amadan Looks good in sqlfiddle. I tried the same code, in Workbench and still it is returning 8 and 8.

Comment: Then, as I said, it's not the matter of Stack Overflow any more - go post a bug report :(.

Comment: Oh, one more thing that might be relevant: which engine is your table using? (though I didn't see a difference there as well, it would be relevant in a bug report)

Comment: @Amadan table is using InnoDB engine

Comment: @Amadan Just occurred that my version was not updated. Before posting the bug report, I updated and now it is working just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in Workbench 8.0.15. It has been rectified in Workbench 8.0.16. An update did the trick.